# Is it still impossible to add downloaded music track to iOS music library?

Tags: ios, download

I would like to offer a downloadable music track and allow users to add it to their iOS music library.

I can see messages from one year and two years ago that say this is impossible. Can someone confirm this is still impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still impossible. You can read from the music library, but not write to it.

I recommend that you [offer the music for free in the iTunes music store](http://www.apple.com/itunes/content-providers/music-faq.html) and simply open a link to it.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus. It does seem that iTunes redemption codes are the only way to go.